# Rails, separate search function within rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I want to embed a search function within a form so a user can search for and select products to submit along with a date range to show availability. I am not sure the best way to do this without submitting all the parameters and trying to handle it in the controller. I am sure there is a rails solution for something like this.

Here is a gist of what I am trying to achieve

```
=simple_form_for [:admin,availability_inspector] do |f|
    = f.text_field :start, type: :text, placeholder: "click to use the date-time picker", class: "form-control auto_picker"
    = f.text_field :finish, type: :text, placeholder: "click to use the date-time picker", class: "form-control auto_picker"
      Stock List Search
      =form_tag new_admin_availability_inspector_path, method: :get do
        =search_field_tag :querystr, params[:querystr], placeholder: "filter", class: "form-control"
        %span.input-group-btn
        =submit_tag "filter", name: nil, class: "btn btn-primary"
  -if @products.any?        
    %ul.list-group
      - @products.each do |product|
        = product.title
          = check_box_tag :product_id, product.id


=f.submit "filter", name: nil, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

So the idea is, the items searched and listed, the user selects the items, and, with the date field range, the form is submitted.

Comment: I understand your problem. Please confirm if you wanted the following thing resolution to be achieved?
1. When dates are changed, your product list will be updated?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. No, I just need to select products through a search. Selected products are then passed to the form to be searched with the dates. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden array field in the form called products. outside the form handle products search,selection and update of that hidden field via Ajax call.

Check this [link](http://archive.railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=1129), Its a similar but simpler example cause he just want to add addresses dynamically while you still have the products searching handled via Ajax first. Please note that the only part you need from his solution is how he updates the form with new fields via JavaScript the rest of details are not relevant.

Comment: can you demonstrate this please?

Comment: You can try this [link](http://archive.railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=1129) it is simpler cause he just want to add addresses dynamically while you still have the products searching handled via Ajax first if it does not help I will demo more when near keyboard.

Comment: which link? I dont think you posted it?

Comment: just to be clear the only part you need from his solution is how he updates the form with new fields via javascript the rest of details are not relevant.

Comment: could you mould this into an answer above please? then the green tick is yours ;)

Comment: You mean you are having an issue with the concept or the implementation? ie: you want further explanation or your code isn't working ?

Comment: Hi Peter, the above answer didn't provide much. I was hoping for an gist of sorts or something. Apologies, but this is unchartered territory so I'll require spoon feeding!

Comment: ok will try to provide an example, you want the form to pass the products parameter as a array products[] or something else ?

Comment: ie: what's the relation type between this form and the products.